# Creating a visual storyboard based upon app delegate using custom class for Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, uinavigationcontroller

Edit: How to I add a login View Controller in this repository:
https://github.com/gazolla/MapTable-Swift

I want to take what is in AppDelagate and create it visually with storyboard so that it 
1) Isn't called immediately when I compile the code and 
2) So I can make everything else with the storyboard going forward.
I added the new Storyboard and created a UIViewController with an embedded NavigationController but I can't create the custom of MyCustomClassViewController.

Here is the code AppDelagate is using below. How do I mimic this using storyboard?

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?


func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

   self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    let v = Venue(aIdent:1, aName: "", aAddress: "", aCity: "", aCategoryName: "", aLat: "", aLng: "")

    var venuesArr : Array<Venue> = []
    venuesArr.append(v)



    let vtv:TableMapViewController = TableMapViewController(frame: self.window?.frame as CGRect!)
    vtv.setVenueCollection(venuesArr)
    let nav:UINavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vtv)

    self.window!.rootViewController =  nav

    self.window!.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using storyboard and if your navigation controller is the initial point of application, you can get it directly as below.

```
let navigation = self.window!.rootViewController as! UINavigationController
```

If you want to set explicitly, you can do as below.

```
let nav = runTestStoryBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("UINavigationController") as! UINavigationController// Give navigation controller identifier as UINavigationController in storyboard.

let abc = runTestStoryBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MyCustomViewController") as! MyCustomViewController// Give this view controller identifier as MyCustomViewController in storyboard.
```

If you want to have abc as root view controller you can do as below.

```
nav.viewControllers = [abc
```

Here is a solution to put view controller(your login view controller)

1. Create a view controller - LogInViewController.
2. Set this one as window's root view controller in appdelegate didFInishLoading method.
3. In LogInViewController after log in success call a method `changeRootViewController()`. This method will be in appdelegate class.
4. In AppDelegate class create the above method `func changeRootViewController()` where you will change the root view controller of window from log in view controller to navigation controller. Now your app will smooth flow acress scrrens.

Comment: TLDR; How do I add a login screen as my initial View Controller and segue to this Navigation Controller
AppDelagate creates the Navigation Controller using the code above (see full edited code above). I want to get rid of this in AppDelagate, create a new UIViewController.swift (or UINavigationController not sure which one to insert it in) file and insert the code there instead but not have the code explicitly state that this ViewController/NavigationController is the initial view controller so I can put  a Login Screen b4 it in storyboard and perform a segue to this navigation controller.

Comment: If i understand your question correctly, If you want to put a view controller before navigation controller you can do it. See my edited answer.